# Docker Swarm with docker compose version 3 hostname underscore issue

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have created a docker swarm and trying to use overlay network in order to communicate between the 2 services deployed over that swarm.
the Docker compose of 1 service looks like:

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    container_name: "eureka"
    image: eureka
    environment:
      EUREKA_HOST: eureka
    ports:
      - 8070:8070
    networks:
      - net_swarm
networks:
  net_swarm:
    external:
      name: net_swarm
```

Second :

```
version: '3'
services:
  web:
    image: zuul-service
    environment:
      EUREKA_HOST: eureka_web
    ports:
      - 8069:8069
    networks:
      - net_swarm
networks:
  net_swarm:
    external:
      name: net_swarm
```

i did a `docker deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml eureka` to create the service 1, which spun up with service name as eureka_web, as seen above the same is referenced in the compose file of service 2 as EUREKA_HOSTS, however since this "eureka_web" has an underscore the host isnt getting picked when trying to run the second file.(primarily becoz of the underscore)
Can i somehow override the underscore in the service name or is there any other work around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't give the container name.

So that your service name will act as the host name.

Also the host name with underscores should not cause any problem. Try finding out the actual rootcause.

Edit:
Your service name and the host name is web. And I can't say about this line, without looking at the docker file.

```
environment:
  EUREKA_HOST: eureka
```

Comment: service name with underscores can not be used as a valid DNS when referred from other container, there are lot of people facing this problem, another thing i have tried without container name, the docker deploy command anyway ignored container_name property

Comment: When the field EUREKA_HOST: eureka is used the error is can not find host, when it is EUREKA_HOST: eureka_web its says host can not be null

Comment: I have personally used several containers with hostnames containing underscores, without any issue like this

Comment: the problem arises when you try to access one container from another like http://my_container_1:9002/eureka

Comment: Instead of setting the hostname by yourself, let the docker set with the service name.

Comment: i think you might wnna have a look at the docker deploy --help one has to provide a name which is prefixed to the service name with an underscore in between, btw which version of compose u are using

Comment: "docker deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml eureka" in this command, you are passing eureka as the swarm cluster name. So it is prefixed to your service name. But that is not involved in the hostname. The container's hostname = service name, given there are no replicas set in that service

Comment: And I hope you are creating the swarm network like this :
docker network create --driver overlay --scope swarm net_swarm

Comment: Yes so when i do the above command and do a #docker-service ls the result is: ID                  NAME                MODE                REPLICAS            IMAGE                 PORTS
pe0yq9kw8oxb        eureka_web    replicated          1/1                 eureka:latest   *:8069->8069/tcp and in order to access the container from other container here i have to access it as service name which has a underscore

Comment: Yes swarm is created like that only

Comment: OMG. How many times do I have to say it.  eureka_web is the service name displayed by the docker service ls command. The hostname of your service is just 'web'. The prefix is to differentiate between the different swarm clusters. Also, give different service name in your second compose file

Comment: I am facing a strange issue where in the extra_hosts entry when i do a docker-compose up shows up in the /etc/hosts of the container, however when i use docker deploy that entry gets ignored: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49511324/docker-deploy-stack-extra-hosts-ignored any thoughts?